# Not able to connect to a Win Xp server with MySql

Tags: mysql, performance, connection

I used to use a `Very old version of MySQL`, and it's getting slow. I tried to use the new `MySQL 5.6.12`community server.

Testing this new version, I found that it works perfect when the server is a `Win8`
But when I tried it on a `WinXP server`, it works local, but the others computers can't acess the database remote.

Is there any known issue with this new version in `winXp` ?
Another thing, is there any `MySQL command` to improve the performance of my software ?
If I found such commands, I would not need to update the `MySQL`.

**Message Error**

```
can obtain database list from server mysql
```

I checked: `Show Variables Like 'skip_networking`` and its **OFF**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out the answer:

I had to grant privilages for the `ROOT` of the remote computer that would acess the server.

Like:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILAGES ON * . * TO root@'ip_machine' IDENTIFIED BY 'PasswordOfTheMySqlOfTheRemoteMachine'
```

Without the spaces in the `* . *`.

Then it's solved...

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things can block connections to your machine:

- a firewall on your WinXP server
- `skip_networking` in the MySQL server configuration
- no access rights for root@some-ip, but only for root@localhost

Error messages would really help ;)

And you should now, that official support for WinXP will end soon. So I would not recommend installing new software on a Win XP machine.

Edit: 
Ho do you connect to your server? What program do you use?